# Print multidimensional array index in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, indexing, printing

hello can you help me to find the way to print the index of a multidimensional array

My script

```
<Php?
$a= array();
$a[0][0][0] = 0;
$a[0][0][1] = 1;
$a[0][1][0] = 2;
$a[0][1][1] = 3;
$a[1][0][0] = 4;
$a[1][0][1] = 5;
$a[1][1][0] = 6;
   
foreach( $a as $v){
    foreach( $v as $v1 ){
        foreach ($v1 as $v2=>$value){
            echo"[][][$v2] = $value\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

//Result//

```
[][][0] = 0
[][][1] = 1
[][][0] = 2
[][][1] = 3
[][][0] = 4
[][][1] = 5
[][][0] = 6
```

Comment: your question is not that much clear cloud you defin more,
but what I am getting from your question is that you want to print the indexes alongs with its value right try this

echo"[$V][$V1][$v2] = $value\n";

Comment: Do the first two foreach loops in the same way as you did the third one - then you have access to the keys from all three levels.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print `[0][0][0] = 0` ? If not please explain what you want to print rather that what you are printing

Comment: Seems like you are close with your last loop. `foreach($a as $b => $c)` gives you the index at `$b` and the value at `$c`, while `foreach($a as $b)` only gives you the value at `$b`. Good variable names can help in a situation like this sometimes, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you might want to print like this.

```
$a = [];
$a[0][0][0] = 0;
$a[0][0][1] = 1;
$a[0][1][0] = 2;
$a[0][1][1] = 3;
$a[1][0][0] = 4;
$a[1][0][1] = 5;
$a[1][1][0] = 6;
   
foreach( $a as $i => $v){
    foreach( $v as $i1 => $v1 ){
        foreach ($v1 as $i2=>$value){
            echo"[$i][$i1][$i2] = $value\n";
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
[0][0][0] = 0
[0][0][1] = 1
[0][1][0] = 2
[0][1][1] = 3
[1][0][0] = 4
[1][0][1] = 5
[1][1][0] = 6
```